# C# Visual Studio System.Windows.Media does not exist in Program Files (x86)\Referenced Assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I couldn't see System.Windows.Media in the list of references, so I followed the advice in previous questions about adding PresentationCore.dll. When that didn't resolve my problem, I searched Program Files (x86)\Referenced Assemblies\Microsoft, and as far as I can tell, there are no files named System.Windows.Media on my computer in any location, whatsoever. What should I do?

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms application you are trying to use?

Comment: WPF. And I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET v4.5, if any of that is relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

System.windows.media is not a reference however it's a namespace and must be used as one, this namespace lives in either PresentationFramework.dll or PresentationCore.dll depending if you are using Windows forms or WPF

Try adding either one of the .dll files and then add "using system.windows.media"

P.S. path for presentationcore.dll is c:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/WPF/PresentationCore.dll

Comment: I already did that prior to writing the question, but it didn't work. System.Windows.Media still doesn't exist.

Comment: Try reinstalling .NET framework https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: I also tried adding the PresentationCore.dll in that folder, and that did not work either.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with .NET framework. Try reinstalling it and let see.

Comment: I think I agree with you, but I'm having trouble resolving it. When I tried the download link, the installer said the installation was blocked because "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 was already a part of this operating system"
The only option was "close", so I clicked that. After I tried to find Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 in the list of installed programs in the control panel, but it didn't exist, so I can't uninstall it or repair it.

Comment: Got you.. is this a fresh installation of windows? Maybe check for Windows updates? As soon as I get home I will try to help you resolve it.

Comment: I checked for updates, which did not resolve my problem. It is not a fresh install of Windows 10.

Comment: If you navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\ will you find Framework64? if so what directories are inside it?

Comment: Also try running .NET repair tool from microsoft, link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Comment: Do a FIND for PresentationCore.dll on your hard drive in Windows Explorer.